# How I cancel promise in axios interceptors (Promise.reject without catch)

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios, interceptor

I would like to handle any api error via axios interceptors. However, returning only Promise.reject (error) without catch I have an error: "uncaught exception: Object"
interceptors.js:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
 return response.data;
}, function (error) {
 if (error.response.status === 401) {
    window.location.replace("/login");
}
return Promise.reject(error.response);
});
```

call.js

```
return axios.get("/users")
.then(data => {
  return data.users;
})
.then(users => {
  this.isTableLoading = false;
  this.bodyData = users;
  });
```

I tried:

- add 1 global catch in only interceptors with:

  - Promise.resolve(error) return error: "TypeError: data is undefined";
  - new Promise(() => {}) work, but this is ugly...

is there a nice solution for this?

Comment: Why you don't want to catch an error from promise just after then? Have you tried to use async/await way?

Comment: I would like to handle every error in interceptors, without adding a catch to each request. I'm using vuex to execute some request,so i guess i can't use async

Comment: Same beahvoir if you `return Promise.reject(error)` instead of error.response?

Comment: Regarding vuex and async, yes you can (and should) inside actions

Comment: @ninka436 If you want to handle the error in the interceptor, then you must not `return Promise.reject(…)`, but actually handle the error and return a usable result. Otherwise, no, you still need a `.catch()` on every request you make, for handling non-401 errors. There is no way around that.